# How to handle Content-Type=application/json;charset=utf-16 in express application and send compatible response

Tags: node.js, express, utf-16, utf

I have an express server, I have to handle a POST call with header:
UNICODE: YES
CONTENT-LENGTH: 130
CONTENT-TYPE:application/json;charset=utf-16

And have to send a compatible response as well.

I am getting the following error in postman

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Bad Request</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for server where it is getting error:

```
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false }));
```

In logs, i found the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/home/ubuntu/KountPlatform/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/home/ubuntu/KountPlatform/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /home/ubuntu/KountPlatform/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/ubuntu/KountPlatform/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/ubuntu/KountPlatform/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/ubuntu/KountPlatform/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: could you show us source code of server? This seems more like validation problem then a problem with headers. Also request that you are sending would be of great help.

Comment: @IvanVasiljevic made the changes

Comment: It seems that JSON object that you are sending is starting with #. So it seems this is problem with request, client, not the backend, server

Comment: No, it is not, the json request is valid, i am sending it from postman, if json was wrong, it would have thrown error in Postman only.